# When I try to install pygame using python 3.9 I get an error windows

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.9

There s currently no version of [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) for python 3.9

Comment: @Rabbid76

That outputs an error too long to type here

Comment: pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6 doesn't work either

Comment: `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev12` (latest)

Comment: @Rabbid76 same result. It pauses at ` Collecting pygame==2.0.0.dev12
  Using cached pygame-2.0.0.dev12.tar.gz (5.6 MB)` before outputting an error

Comment: Try the [unofficial packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) from  Christoph Gohlke, others have found that useful.

Comment: @TheTroupeMaster please leave the question intact after receiving an answer... If you wish to answer the question then do so only as a new answer...

Answer (score 0):

As of https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2163 there are prebuilt binaries for Python 3.9 starting with pygame version `2.0.0.dev14`.

```
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev14
```

Answer (score 0):

My question is exactly the same as yours. I have tried many methods, but none of them will work. But I succeeded after using this.
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev14