# installing pygame ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python

hello guys I have been trying to install pygame but whenever I do I get this error message and I have tried many solutions from YouTube unfortunately none of them worked, in fact I have tried installing sql and many other libraries but had the same error please help.

```
C:\Users\pCd>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: 'c:\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pCd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i9uohpid\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pCd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i9uohpid\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\pCd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-n48e7goc'
cwd: C:\Users\pCd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i9uohpid\pygame\Complete output (17 lines):

WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pCd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i9uohpid\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module> buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\pCd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i9uohpid\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\pCd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i9uohpid\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\pCd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i9uohpid\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using? If you are using python 3.9.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261106/when-i-try-to-install-pygame-using-python-3-9-i-get-an-error-windows#:~:text=As%20of%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub,starting%20with%20pygame%20version%202.0.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got a way how to fix this issue. basically you all just to uninstall python completely and re-install it but with version 3.6
you all can download it using this URL: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/python-3.6.8-amd64.exe

Comment: You can close this question now, as you found the solution.